# How to retrieve specific queried array collections in MongoDB using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've just tried MongoDB & NodeJS and having issue in finding specific array collections using Nodejs.

Here's the the collections I have :

```
    {
  "_id": ObjectId("552aa4da6e25e57ebde7ac6f"),
  "username": "blablabla",
  "email": "xxx@gmail.com",
  "password": "Dummy Trip",
  "itinerary": [
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("552c109adb616795044a919e"),
      "title": "test-0",
      "desc": "test-0-desc"
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("552c10b0db616795044a91a0"),
      "title": "test-1",
      "desc": "test-1-desc"
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("552c1128db616795044a91a1"),
      "title": "test-2",
      "desc": "test-2-desc"
    }
  ]
}
```

So I need to find the array of itinerary that has objecId of "552c109adb616795044a919e"

In MongoDB terminal I use findOne command & positional $ operator and it works as expected, showing only the array I search for.

Command :

```
db.user.findOne({ "itinerary._id" : ObjectId("552c109adb616795044a919e") }, {"itinerary.$" : 1})
```

Result :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("552aa4da6e25e57ebde7ac6f"),
"itinerary" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("552c109adb616795044a919e"),
        "title" : "test-0",
        "desc" : "test-0-desc"
    }
]}
```

But why when I tried to implement it in NodeJS, it shows all records instead of the specific array I search.

Here's my NodeJS :

```html
        var userCollection = db.get('user');
userCollection.findOne({ "itinerary._id" : new ObjectID("552c109adb616795044a919e") }, {"itinerary.$" : 1},function(e,userDocs){
 console.log(userDocs);
});
```

NodeJS Result (Showing all results) :

```html
{
  _id: 552aa4da6e25e57ebde7ac6f,
  username: 'blablabla',
  email: 'xxx@gmail.com',
  password: 'Dummy Trip',
  itinerary: [
{
  _id: 552c109adb616795044a919e,
  title: 'test-0',
  desc: 'test-0-desc'
},
{
  _id: 552c10b0db616795044a91a0,
  title: 'test-1',
  desc: 'test-1-desc'
},
{
  _id: 552c1128db616795044a91a1,
  title: 'test-2',
  desc: 'test-2-desc'
}
  ]
}
```

Did I miss something here ?

**Note :**

- I'm using Node MongoDB native driver

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @Pier-LucGendreau thanks, but it returns null

Comment: The Node driver and the shell have different syntax for projections. You need to specify the `fields` field of the second `options` argument. See [the API docs for findOne](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#findOne).

Comment: Thanks @wdberkeley, I have read the docs and implemented it but it still returns all the itinerary content instead of the queried itinerary content. I only need to get 1 of the 3 itineraries that I searched. After reading some resource, I found out that field selection is just for object, not for an array, while the itinerary I have is array of object. Hmm what do you think ?

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming your `itinerary` is an array. then you will have to use  `$elemMatch` in mongodb.More details on [elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/).

You can try something like.

```
 var userCollection = db.get('user');
 userCollection.findOne({ "itinerary": { $elemMatch: {_id: new ObjectID("552c109adb616795044a919e")}}}, {"itinerary.$" : 1},function(e,userDocs){
console.log(userDocs);
});
```

Also i think for matching object id you can use `mongoose.Types.ObjectId("552c109adb616795044a919e")`

Comment: hmm.. I tried to use $elemMatch as you suggested above, but it still returns all array instead of returning the specific one